# How to set default keyboard layout for GDM 3.16?

Tags: keyboard, gnome, arch-linux, keyboard-layout, gdm

I have two keyboard layout (Colemak and Qwerty). When I have logged into my Gnome session my keyboard layout is set to Colemak automatically. But for some reason I can't change the default GDM keyboard. So I either have to enter my password in Qwerty or change it every time GDM starts.

I'm using Arch Linux with Gnome 3.16.

Edit: I've tried to follow the instruction on the GDM article at the Arch Linux Wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#GDM_keyboard_layout). But I cannot find the `Login Screen` menu from `gnome-control-center`.

Edit 2: I've tried launch `gnome-control-center` as root and change the keyboard, it doesn't works.

Answer (score 6):

I'd been having the same problem for a long time and encountered https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Desktop_Migration_and_Administration_Guide/customizing-login-screen.html which says to use `localectl set-x11-keymap` for changing the system layout such that GDM will honor it. I checked `localectl` on my system, and it did return `us` as my keyboard layout.

In my case the following seems to have fixed it, even though the on screen keyboard still shows in us qwerty:

```
# localectl set-keymap dvorak
```

Obviously, substitute `dvorak` for whatever layout you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and I fixed it by setting both :

```
localectl set-keymap fr
```

and

```
localectl set-x11-keymap fr
```

where `fr` is my keymap, so in your specific case it would be

```
localectl set-x11-keymap colemak
localectl set-keymap colemak
```

I hope that I helped you, don't hesitate to ask if I wasn't clear, this is my first answer on SuperUser